# Should the required Covid19 documentation be printed on paper when travelling to France?

Tags: paperwork, covid-19

Currently according to [the Ryan Air website](https://www.ryanair.com/ie/en/plan-trip/travel-documentation) entering France requires filling two specific forms due to the Covid19 situation:

- [A sworn statement of absence of symptoms](https://www.ryanair.com/content/dam/ryanair/comms-2020/swornstatement-EN_compressed.pdf), officially required by [French authorities](https://www.interieur.gouv.fr/Actualites/L-actu-du-Ministere/Attestation-de-deplacement-et-de-voyage)
- A [passenger locator form](https://www.ryanair.com/content/dam/ryanair/comms-2020/FR-paxlocator-EN_compressed.pdf) (which seems to be a requirement from Ryan Air)

I would like to know if these documents must be printed on paper, or is it enough to have them in electronic format in my phone?

Comment: When dealing with this sort of bureaucracy it is always better to bring a printed copy of the required documents.

Comment: @JoErNanO yes I agree, but I don't have easy access to a printer so in case it's not necessary I was hoping somebody might be able to confirm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have recently traveled to France from the UK as a tourist (3rd of August). Not by plane, but by car(/train), but I think the protocols are similar.

The sworn statement should be printed and signed. And it should be handed to the security officer with your other travel documents (i.e. passport, visa). My advice is to print this form in advance and fill out the form on the day you will travel to France. The French authorities will check your passport and the will scan the printed form. And they will keep the form for their reference.

The [public health passenger locator card](https://www.who.int/ihr/ports_airports/locator_card/en/) (passenger locator form) is a form provided by the WHO rather than the french authorities.

> This passenger locator card provides an appropriate method of rapidly
> collecting passenger contact information and is recommended to be used
> when public health authorities suspect the potential for disease
> transmission on board an aircraft and a subsequent need for contact
> tracing. The information is intended to be held by public health
> authorities in accordance with applicable law and is to be used only
> for authorized public health purposes.

This form should also be filled out. Unless stated otherwise you will also need to print this form and hand it over to Ryanair upon checkin or boarding at the airport.

*As the situation is different for each country and can change in a matter of days or even hours, I would recommend to do requested tasks the best way possible. The authorities want to be sure that you are not infected and that you won't get infected.*

Answer (score 2):

If you scroll down the page you linked to, you will notice there is a link to a website to submit all the info required for a trip to and from the French overseas territorities and generate a QR code. Something similar was introduced mid-way through the lock-down in March-April. Nothing is available for trips to mainland France from abroad.

That's a clear sign that when the authorities intend to allow these forms to be used electronically, they will explicitely provide a solution to fill them in that way. If none is available, the form must be printed.

Answer (score 0):

The link is only for the passenger locator form, the question asks about the sworn statement.

So it seems for now this must be printed. Local libraries often offer printing services and theres plenty of other stores that do this too.

Theres really no excuse for not having the proper documentation, you will be stopped and refused entry to your flight.